# Is it possible to get file access with flash player runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, web, actionscript

i'm trying to do a recording application with flash ( IE9, requirement ) - i'm wondering whether there is a possibility to get **uninterrupted access to user's file system** to save parts of a long recording ( more than 2 hours ) ( large parts 200 mb). So that when by mistake, he closes browser tab, his recording progress is not totally lost ?

Comment: most likely it is impossible

Comment: You can use the browser's local storage by using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).  Most browsers give you 5mb or more to start.  Same principle as @Brians's answer.    There's also [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) which can offer even more storage

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, this is possible.  Sort of.**

Because you're publishing for web, you're limited to the [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class, which can only save to the local filesystem by opening a save dialog box for the user.

However, you can cache the recording data with [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) without needing user intervention every time.

Note that the user will need to authorize storage once you try to cache data beyond the storage limit (default 100k).  This is an improvement over `FileReference` as the user won't need to click something for *every* caching operation, but it still requires user intervention at least once to allow the process.

Comment: can i save 200 mb using SharedObject API, i know that the user has to allow for it ( but if he does ) - is it possible ?

Comment: nothing in de documentation mentions a max size, trial and error I reckon.

Comment: Max size in the control panel is "unlimited".  As for if it's possible - you'll just have to try it.  I wouldn't be surprised by performance problems, but I've never actually pushed `SharedObject` to its breaking point.